# Can't target ID of an element in a loop using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm stumped and need some help. I am trying to implement some responsive code, upon implementation, I had to re-jigger some code to make it work. One being getting the ID from a table element. 
The HTML I have so far:

```
<div class="title">blah</div>
<table id="Sailing%20Monohull" class="responsive">
    <!-- contents -->
</table>
```

When you go responsive, the HTML changes, like so:

```
<div class="title">blah</div>
<div class="table-wrapper">
    <div class="scrollable">
        <table id="Sailing%20Monohull" class="responsive">
            <!-- contents -->
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="pinned">
        <table id="Sailing%20Monohull" class="responsive">
            <!-- contents -->
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is repeated 3 times. When responsive, I want to get the table ID, example "Sailing%20Monohull"
I have tried in Chrome's console:

```
$(".title").each(function(index, element) {
    console.log($(this).next().find('.scrollable').children().attr('id'));
});
```

and I got the desired results. but when I put it in my file, upload it and run it, I get undefined and I don't know why. I am open to any ideas. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your table id is not a valid identifier. Do not use special characters, except for _. Use number or characters.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Only spcaeing characters are illegal characters in `id`s in HTML5.

Comment: A valid identifier can only begin with a alphabet or underscore, nothing else. And other characters in the identifier can contain numbers, characters or _, no special characters alllowed.

Comment: [Nope](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute).

Comment: Even with the invalid identifier, it still works. I can still get the ID.

Comment: @Teemu - Pls check http://jsfiddle.net/jdk8urdm/ and the console too.

Comment: Please check the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) ; ). Also CSS might not accept such of `id`s though they are valid in HTML5.

Comment: @NikhilPai, http://jsfiddle.net/jdk8urdm/1/

Comment: @Teemu, however, it is better not to use special characters in tag id, because it reduces code readability.

Comment: @th1rdey3 Yes, but my point was just disagree with the incorrect answer. Also, what OP says in the comment to Sadikshasan's answer, the problem most likely lies in the timing, and has nothing to do with `id`s.

Comment: @Teemu, I am just clearing it for other readers. They might get tempted to use special characters in tag IDs. Which is not a good practice.

Comment: Just a query - What is OP?

Comment: @NikhilPai OP is either "Original Poster" or "Original Post".

Comment: @NikhilPai overpowered! Ah, sorry, to much gaming. Teemu is right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".title").each(function(index, element) {
    console.log($(this).next("div").find('.scrollable').find("table").attr("id"));
});
```

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6nhmabnk/)**

Comment: While this works in your Fiddle and in my console, I plop it into my code and run it and I get "undefined". The responsive HTML comes into play at a certain width, would that be a reason as to why I can't target the ID?